# Upper bound of the fraction of gamma functions

Tags: inequality, special-functions, gamma-function

Is there a simple upper bound of the following fraction of gamma functions for any $a,b\geq 0$:
$$\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b)}$$

The upper bound should be in the form: there is a constant $C$, such that 
$$\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b)}\leq C f(a,b),$$
where $f=\frac{a+b}{a}$

Comment: What about $C=1$ and $f(a, b) = \frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b)}$? – You have to more specific what kind of upper bound you are looking for.

Comment: I haven't worked it out, but using Stirling's approximation $\Gamma(x) \sim (2\pi)^{1/2}x^{x-1/2} e^{-x} $ as $x \to \infty$ might be helpful.

Comment: I would like a bound in terms of $(a+b)/a$. I need an inequality-not approximation

Comment: Not really a full answer, or what you're looking for, but
$$\frac{\Gamma(x+y)}{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(y)}<\frac{x^{y-1}}{\Gamma(y)}\left(1+\frac{y}{2x}\right)^{y-1}.$$ See: http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/29/0006/

Comment: @Anna I don't get you. What do you think an asymptotic equivalence is? $f(x) \sim g(x)$ is equivalent to saying $f(x) = g(x) + o(g(x))$